# How to remove dataframe index and list(zip) brackets

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

My code -

```
df=pd.read_csv("file")

import numpy as np
def get_lengths(s):
    cols = s.index[::2]
    labels = s.index[::2]
    l = list(np.cumsum(list(map (len, s[cols]))))
    l = list(zip([0]+l[:-1], l))
    
    return (' '.join(s[cols]), {'entities': list(zip(l, labels))})


data_fr= df.apply(get_lengths, axis=1)
print(data_fr)
data_fr.to_json("file")
```

The output I am getting -

```
{"0":["House 263 dhaka mirpur",{"entities":[[[0,9],"house"],[[9,14],"district"],[[14,20],"area"]]}],"1":["House 31 comilla badda",{"entities":[[[0,8],"house"],[[8,15],"district"],[[15,20],"area"]]}],"2":["House 193\/A chittagong dohs",{"entities":[[[0,11],"house"],[[11,21],"district"],[[21,25],"area"]]}]}
```

My expected output-

```
["House 263 dhaka mirpur",{"entities":[[0,9,"house"],[10,15,"district"],[16,21,"area"]]}],["House 31 comilla badda",{"entities":[[0,7,"house"],[9,15,"district"],[17,21,"area"]]}]
```

Mainly I want to

- remove "0", "1" etc indexes
- remove [ ], where I am calculating the string length. Instead of writing it is as `[[0,9],"house"]`, I want it as `[0,9,"house"]`

My dataframe-

My dataframe - [image]

```
{'house': {0: 'House 263', 1: 'House 31', 2: 'House 193/A'}, 'holding_number': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1}, 'district': {0: 'dhaka', 1: 'comilla', 2: 'chittagong'}, 'district.1': {0: 'ty', 1: 'err', 2: 'err'}, 'area': {0: 'mirpur', 1: 'badda', 2: 'dohs'}, 'area.1': {0: 'fcd', 1: 'dfdfs', 2: 'fcd'}}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the dataframe in text form (so we can copy-paste it)?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I have edited my question. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
out = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    name = " ".join(map(str.strip, row[::2]))
    entities = []
    i = 0
    for n in row.index[::2]:
        entities.append([i, i + len(row[n]) - 1, n])
        i += len(row[n]) + 1
    out.append([name, {"entities": entities}])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [
        "House 263 dhaka mirpur",
        {"entities": [[0, 8, "house"], [10, 14, "district"], [16, 21, "area"]]},
    ],
    [
        "House 31 comilla badda",
        {"entities": [[0, 7, "house"], [9, 15, "district"], [17, 21, "area"]]},
    ],
    [
        "House 193/A chittagong dohs",
        {
            "entities": [
                [0, 10, "house"],
                [12, 21, "district"],
                [23, 26, "area"],
            ]
        },
    ],
]
```

Comment: it's counting wrong. It should be [
        "House 263 dhaka mirpur",
        {"entities": [[0, 8, "house"], [10, 14, "district"], [16, 21, "area"]]}]

Comment: @bellatrix Please update your expected output in your question then.

Comment: can you please look into my expected output again? I have to count the spaces for for the first ones but not for the last.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you are asking for:

```
import numpy as np
def get_lengths(s):
    cols = s.index[::2]
    labels = s.index[::2]
    l = list(np.cumsum(list(map (len, s[cols]))))
    l = list(zip([0]+l[:-1], l))
    l1 = (e[0] for e in l)
    l2 = (e[1] for e in l)
    return (' '.join(s[cols]), {'entities': list(zip(l1, l2, labels))})


data_fr= df.apply(get_lengths, axis=1)
data_fr.to_json("file", orient='records')
```

Basically, I split l = [(a0,b0),(a1,b1)] into l1 and l2. It is not the most efficient way to do it, but it works
For pd.Series type, if you do not what to keep key in to_json, you can orient='records' as a parameter.

Comment: I have updated my question. It's counting the length wrong. Result I got - [["House 263 dhaka mirpur",{"entities":[[0,9,"house"],[9,14,"district"],[14,20,"area"]]}].. It should be - [ "House 263 dhaka mirpur", {"entities": [[0, 8, "house"], [10, 14, "district"], [16, 21, "area"]]}]